# How to disable the touch actions while the other touch event performs in React native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

I am displaying the list item using index values along with a button while I click on the button in one of the list item index other list items should be displaying as disabled. Will it be possible?

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.downloadLessonItems()}}>
 {!this.state.isDownloading && !this.state.isDownloaded &&
  <Image
    style={styles.imgContainer}
    source={this.state.downloadImageURI} />}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `disabled` prop to [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) as it takes  `disabled`  prop from [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#disabled) and it's value should be boolean

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabled} onPress={this._onPressButton}>
  <Image
    style={styles.button}
    source={require('./myButton.png')}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

for your code you can

```
<TouchableOpacity
  disabled={!this.state.isDownloading && !this.state.isDownloaded}
  onPress={() => {this.downloadLessonItems()}}
 >
  {!this.state.isDownloading && !this.state.isDownloaded &&
    <Image style={styles.imgContainer} source={this.state.downloadImageURI} />}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: this.state.disable refers to?

Comment: it's only to control the disabled prop as you can set it to true or false

Comment: Can we also disable the navigation also using disabled?

Comment: disabled will disable the onPress from being executed but I am not sure what navigation you mean

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.downloadLessonItems()}}>
            {!this.state.isDownloading && !this.state.isDownloaded && <Image style={styles.imgContainer}
              source={this.state.downloadImageURI}
            />}
          </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: Above is my code when i click on downloadLessonItems a loader will be displaying and downloaded will be on progress untill the download completes i should not leave the user to perform any action like click on the list items

Comment: I updated my answer for as i understood your comment